# For iOS filter effect not coming while converting canvas image to toDataURL()

Tags: javascript, ios, image, filter, fabricjs

I want the filter effect of an image while converting to base64 image .

```
$scope.maskCanvas = new fabric.Canvas('viewport');          
$scope.maskctx = $scope.maskCanvas.getContext("2d");  
$scope.maskctx.filter = 'contrast(200%)';  
console.log($scope.maskCanvas.toDataURL);
console.log($scope.maskctx.toDataURL);
```

For iOS filter not reflecting on canvas